# Continuous Integration stack on Windows with Mercurial + Mercurial Queues?

Tags: asp.net, mercurial, continuous-integration

We've been using Mercurial with Mercurial Queues (+guards for patches) for source control of a number of Windows ASP.Net projects.

I'm interested in setting up a Continuous Integration environment for this but am getting lost in conflicting reports of success with CC/Trac etc.

I'm wondering who else out there is doing this and what your working stack of apps/utils is?  Also, if you've got hints on workflow, I'm all ears :)

Appreciation in advance!

Answer (score 3):

We use hudson and mercurial together and have been quite successful.  They are both flexible enough to about anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

We are very happy using **Mercurial**/[**Kiln**](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) with [**TeamCity**](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

Answer (score 0):

Which CruiseControl?

If the Java version I know people use it with both Trac and Mercurial, though I don't have the experience with those myself.

But you can ask on the CruiseControl [users mailing list](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/contact.html) to see what others are doing...

Answer (score 0):

We're using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) & [BuildBot](http://www.buildbot.net). Works resonably well for simple usage of Mercurial.

Commit-hooks are available for both, but you might have to dig a bit,